# Set Silverlight combobox selected item from string name

Tags: c#, silverlight

I am trying to set the selected item in my silverlight combobox from a string.

In this example lets say I have a combobox named "MyComboBox" as follows:

```
<ComboBox Height="23" x:Name="MyComboBox" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="0" Content="Pizza" IsSelected="True"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="1" Content="Soda"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="2" Content="Wings"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="3" Content="Bread Sticks"/>
</ComboBox>
```

I am randomly selecting a string value above from a list to simulate a users saved preference.  The problem I am facing is trying to grab the index of "MyComboBox" from a string.

I've tried using MyComboBox.items wtih LINQ but that has taken me nowhere.

There are some similar questions here on stack overflow but none of these have been answered.

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just setting `MyComboBox.SelectedItem`?

Comment: Did you tried MyComboBox.SelectdValue?

Comment: @Stephan that is what I am tring to do but there is no way to convert a string to a comboboxitem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a reason that you have to wrap the strings in `ComboBoxItem` then this should work.

```
MyComboBox.Items.SelectedItem = 
    MyComboBox.Items.SingleOrDefault(c => (c as ComboBoxItem).Content == myString);
```

I would recommend to not directly insert `ComboBoxItem` and set items to `String` or setup a collection in code and bind to it.

Comment: The only modification I did was to add .ToString() at the end of the .Content to compare string values

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the following.

```
SetSelectedItem("Pizza");
```

/// Set selected item as string.

```
    private void SetSelectedItem(string selectedString)
    {
        Func<ComboBoxItem, ComboBoxItem> selectionFunc = (item) =>
        {
            if(item.Content.ToString() == selectedString)
                return item;
            return null;
        };

        this.MyComboBox.SelectedItem = MyComboBox.Items.Select(s => selectionFunc(s as ComboBoxItem)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi i am applied function for encountred index in Combobox

```
private int Search_Item_Return_Index(ComboBox combo, string Search)
     {
         int index=-1;

         foreach (ComboBoxItem item in combo.Items)
         {
             index++;
             string var = item.Content.ToString() ;
             if (var.Equals(Search))
             {
                 return index;
             }

         }


         return index;

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting strings into the combobox then you can use

```
MyComboBox.Items.IndexOf("Pizza")
```

Comment: All this returns is -1 no matter what I set inside of the IndexOf

Comment: Are you adding Strings to the ComboBox? If you do MyComboBox.Items[0], what type of object do you get back?

Comment: @KeithMahney System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem

Comment: As I said, this works if you are adding strings to the combobox.  If you set  var myPizzaObject = new Food("Pizza");  MyComboBox.Items.Add(myPizzaObject);  then, if its selected, the MyComboBox.SelectedItem is your myPizzaObject.  To find it you would need to have a reference to myPizzaObject stored somewhere, and use MyComboBox.Items.IndexOf(myPizzaObject).

Comment: is there any way to get the Index of if you are not adding strings to it but are defining the comboboxitems how I have it in my updated question/example?

Answer (score 0):

I see,  you can add a name to the xaml

```
<ComboBoxItem Tag="0" Name="CBIPizza" IsSelected="True" Content="Pizza" />
```

then use

```
MyComboBox.Items.IndexOf(CBIPizza);
```

---

or...  Make the items strings instead using

```
  <ComboBox Name="MyComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Items>
            <sys:String>Pizza</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Bread Sticks</sys:String>
      </ComboBox.Items>
```

which of course requires defining

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Then the original example would work